# Microsoft Bot Framework: broadcast messages to users from database

Tags: c#, frameworks, bots

Situation: When a user registers for a bot (by entering a message to the bot, I store the information of that user in a database:
- UserId
- UserName,
- ServiceURL

At some point in time I want to have my bot broadcast a message to all the users in that table.

```
foreach (var bUsers in users)
{
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(bUsers.ServiceUrl);
                        MicrosoftAppCredentials creds = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("<<appid>>", "<<secret>>");
                        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(bUsers.ServiceUrl), creds);
                        var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(new ChannelAccount(), new ChannelAccount(bUsers.UserId, bUsers.UserName));
                        message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                        message.From = botAccount;
                        message.Recipient = userAccount;
                        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
                        message.Text = "Hello from " + context.Activity.From.Name;
                        message.Locale = "en-Us";
                        var reply = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity) message);
}
```

With this code, I get a message saying:

> Invalid conversation ID in teamsChannelId

I don't understand this message, and is it even possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing almost the same thing as you do but it stopped working suddenly. I could see the same error message.

But in my case it was just wrong and maybe it's strange it worked in the first place. Because I used `client.UserId` which was set to `activity.Conversation.Id`. If I changed the code to use it as `conversationId` it works.

Here is my code which is working right now and old pieces are commented out:

```
    public static async Task SendMessageToClient(ServerClient client, string messageText)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(client.BotServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
        var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: client.UserName, id: client.UserId);
        var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: client.BotName, id: client.BotId);
        // this worked before but not anymore
        //var conversationId = await connector.Conversations
        //       .CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount).Id;

        // because client.UserId was set in a MessageController to activity.Conversation.Id we can use this
        var conversationId = client.UserId; 
        var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        message.From = botAccount;
        message.Recipient = userAccount;
        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(false, conversationId);
        message.Locale = "en-Us";
        if (client.ReplaceFrom != null && client.ReplaceTo != null)
        {
            messageText = messageText.Replace(client.ReplaceFrom, client.ReplaceTo);
        }
        message.Text = messageText;
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity) message);
    }
```

Comment: In my situation, using the emulator, the bot says nothing anymore. It clears the chat window. Strange thing is it used to work until two days ago. I managed to have a message sent to some Skype Users at the same time.

Comment: Fot future use...

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2294

Seems to be related to an update to 3.5.3